# How to make command arguments identifiable in Eclipse product?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have such argument which is needed in my eclipse product:

```
http://some_url/api/v1/
```

when I debug the app I can use Program Arguments with own argument:

```
${my_api}
```

but it is local argument. When I tried to get arguments from the platform I saw that I only can get strings array:

```
Platform.getApplicationArgs()
```

so each argument has to be at the certain place because programmatically for example I get element on the 1 (0) position. Maybe I can add some keys to identify each program argument and get it like dictionary item for example?

Comment: Program arguments are often a keyword followed by a value such as the standard `-persistState false`.

Comment: yes, but how to get it by key from strings array? I tried to add it in product config tab by that way - `-api ${api}` but I don't see in xml any url mentions and don't sure whether I will be able to get it by key

Comment: The program arguments are on the Launching tab of the product file, the config tab sets the config.ini which sets system properties.

Comment: I understand it, and I need to change some info without total rebuilding the product in jenkins, I also tried to use on the  launching `-Dapi http://url/api/v1/` and then `System.getProperty("api")` but received null, so I have to use config tab for setting data into config.ini file? because I set it and received null too

Comment: Ignore the config.ini. The lauching tab info goes in to the <rcp name>.ini file which is easier to find and modify (always in the same directory as the executable).

Comment: so as I understood I have to use configuration tab where set Properties for further generated product, yes? or I still didn't understand it correctly?)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'further generated product'. None of my RCPs use the config tab properties for anything.

Comment: Note: it would be `-Dapi=http://url/api/v1` - '=' not space

Comment: I mean with 'product' ordinary eclipse product folder with all folders like artifacts, ini file, exe  and so on, and I'm trying to set some value in config.ini and then change it manually and use in eclipse product

Comment: On the Config tab Properties section you would specify a propery name of "api" and a value of what you want. You get the value in the program with `System.getProperty("api")` - I just tested this and it works. Since the product file is only used when the RCP is built this will not be set with running using the Run Configuration.

Comment: ok, it seems that I got it, thank you, I will check it by self, and then will upd the question, because we have too many comments here :(